# Loop through DataFrame output

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and IPython notebooks.

Currently, I have a Logs table with columns `MachineName`, `LocalIPAddress`, `SourceAddress` and `DateTime`.

For each set of unique `MachineName`, `LocalIPAddress` and `SourceAddress`, I have to retrieve their respective DateTime in a list and check how many Logs where logged in the last minute and last hour.

I understand that I have to loop through the columns in *dataframes* and implement the logic.

I am not sure on how to achieve this in IPython.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Please show examples of the data. Your description is a little vague to get an accurate answer. Specifically: a) Is the table a Pandas dataframe, or some other structure? b) How is the list of logs structured - (datetime, logname) pairs or something else?

Comment: @holdenweb

A sample row would be MachineName as "BMTSA" , DateTime as "2016-04-13 23:43:12.06" , LocalIPAddress as "10.20.0.186" and Source Address as "10.21.2.78".

I have to get the System Current Time and  for each unique row combination of MachineName, DateTime and LocalIPAddress, I have to find the number of logs that were logged in the last minute and last hour by comparing the current system time with the DateTime in the table.

Comment: I understand this can be achieved by filtering the dataframes by grouping it on MachineName, LocalIPAddress and SourceAddress and check whether their DateTime's fall within the last minute, last hour and last day.

I am working on the python code now !!

Comment: I tried this code for counting the number of logs that were logged in the last minute - but something goes wrong and I am not getting the correct output.

{

import time

strings = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S")

t = strings.split(',')

numbers = [ int(x) for x in t ]

numbers = numbers[4]

groupby_object = df[['MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress', 'SourceAddress', (('DateTime' > numbers-1) & ('DateTime' <= numbers))]].groupby(['MachineName', 'LocalIPAddress','SourceAddress']).agg(['count'])

}

Comment: You would be better updating your question to include the code and pointing out what output you expect and what you are getting. As you can see, comments don't format the code for easy reading like questions do.